# Django follow / relationships app?

Tags: django

I was looking at Django-follow first but I want something that is a bit more up to date.

Just something for keeping track of related users (or other models). And if it possible to combine with some kind of notifications it would be great. I'm using Django 1.6.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-subscription ?

It's basically what you are asking for. Although if you are looking for facebook- or stackoverflow-like notifications on the front-end, you will need to write some javascript to do that.

Comment: Thanks Emma. I will check it out. Basically what I want is users to 'follow' or keep track of other users (or other models) activities. I guess it would be a combination of different apps in the end to achieve this.

Comment: There's also this https://github.com/natgeo/activitystreams for more complex and more flexible use but it's harder to setup correctly

Comment: Cool thanks! Do you have any experience with Pinax? Seems like many use this app (?) for social-functions. Maybe it's better to go with that from the start.

Comment: I've tried pinax a long time ago. At the time it didn't fit my needs *at all*. But I just took a look at their site right now and it looks like they have expended a lot since then but I couldn't tell you if it's good or not. If I remember well my problem with pinax was that their apps were very much interconnected and made it hard to plug anything else in.

Comment: I think you were right from the beginning Emma. I think the subscription is the way to go. Pinax has a notifications-app but it seems to be for email, and I can't find the documentation for their friends-app (seems outdated anyway..).